# Нужны ли здесь кавычки после "что"?

Tags: кавычки

*Мне становится очень стыдно после того, как я говорю своей маме, что мне сейчас некогда помогать ей*.
Нужны ли здесь кавычки после "что", и если нужны, то почему?

Comment: А какие слова (после **что**) собираетесь брать в кавычки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Мне становится очень стыдно после того, как я говорю своей маме, что **мне сейчас некогда помогать ей.***
Выделенная часть предложения после союза "что" является косвенной речью, поэтому никакие кавычки здесь не требуются.

> Первая, главная часть предложения в этом случае представляет собой слова автора, а вторая – косвенную речь. Обратите внимание: слова автора стоят перед косвенной речью и отделяются от нее запятой. Этот способ передачи чужой речи, в отличие от прямой речи, сохраняет содержание чужого высказывания, но не сохраняет его форму и интонацию.

Я ответил, что мне сейчас не до охоты. [Фазиль Искандер. Сандро из Чегема (Книга 2) (1989)]

Сравните (с прямой речью):
Сказал маме: «Мне сейчас некогда помогать тебе!»
Я ответил: «Мне сейчас не до охоты».

[Чужая речь и способы ее передачи](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_192)

Answer (score 0):

Нет, кавычки не нужны, так как сочетание ‟мне сейчас некогда помогать ей” является косвенной, а не прямой, речью, то есть не является дословной передачей чьей-то речи.